# Mod_rewrite: How to check word with special characters in URL

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have some url's where somehow following keyword appearing

which causes url status to 404. I want to check using .htaccess that if url contains

this form   eg. domain/<\?=BASEURL?>/other_part_of_url

then it will be converted to domain/other_part_of_url

I have tried with

RewriteRule /

for testing purpose I have checked for < only but it is not working.

Comment: This seems to be IISS concerned. Please add "IISS" tag to help people like me skipping these kindof topics.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule /<\?=BASEURL\?>/ /
```

Comment: pattern "<?=BASEURL?>" is appearing in URL. I just want to remove that pattern from URL.

Comment: Do you actually mean it appears literally as `<?=BASEURL?>`? Can you elaborate?

Comment: The problem is elsewhere then ;) If you type your URL directly, you should get the same 403

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```